# Is it possible to create Virtual Serial (COM) Ports

Tags: windows-7, virtualization, serial, emulation

I'm working on software that needs to communicate with hardware over RS232 interfaces.
In order to test I'm currently using 2 USB-TO-SERIAL devices connected to eachother using an RS232 cable. (Of course both USB devices are connected to the same computer).

While it's perfectly possible to test this way, I'm wondering if there is no
way to create 2 virtual com ports on my system and connect them to eachother.

I'm using Windows 7 RC1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are a few commercial options I found after a quick search.

- [Virtual Serial Port](http://www.hw-group.com/products/hw_vsp/index_en.html) by HW group, which is free.
- [Virtual Serial Port Driver](http://www.virtualserialport.com/products/vspdxp/) by Eltima Software.
- [Virtual Serial Port Kit](http://www.fabulatech.com/virtual-serial-port-kit.html) by FabulaTech.

I am not sure if any will support Windows 7, until it is released.

Comment: I kinda like the Eltima Software solution, found it just before reading this post.. I wil buy a licence. Thnx !

Comment: Oh and it does support windows 7

Answer (score 7):

I'm not sure if this will help but I checked out several months ago as a replacement for Digiboards. I haven't actually used it but it seemed that it was useful.

http://com0com.sourceforge.net/

Comment: I've been using this tool and it works like a charm. I spent a lot of time researching similar tools and this is, by far, the best.

Answer (score -1):

Virtual COMM Port Driver (Windows 7 - 10):

http://www.netburner.com/products/netburner-software/deployment-tools

Comment: This is not what the author of the question has been asking for.